# Ubuntu One on Lubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu-one, sync, lubuntu

Is it possible to sync a Ubuntu computer with a Lubuntu computer with Ubuntu One? Can you install Ubuntu One on Lubuntu with no problems?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## 11.10 and previous versions

Lubuntu uses the same base as Ubuntu, so once you install the Ubuntu One client, everything should be fine. Note though that you will not get the same level of integration with PCManFM that you do with Nautilus.

The best UbuntuOne client package to install is `ubuntuone-client-gtk`. You can install this in the Synaptic Package Manager (present by default on Lubuntu systems), in the Software Center (if you have that installed), or in the LXTerminal by running `sudo apt-get update` followed by `sudo apt-get install ubuntuone-client-gtk`.

Comment: I'm editing this to include brief installation instructions, as (1) it would be undesirable to install `ubuntu-client-gnome` since it would pull in GNOME packages as [fossfreedom](http://askubuntu.com/users/14356/fossfreedom) has [commented](http://askubuntu.com/a/62550/22949), and (2) Lubuntu doesn't have `software-center` installed by default.

Comment: @EliahKagan: it has a lubuntu-software-center no? Thanks btw.

Comment: `software-center` is installable on Lubuntu and works fine, but it is not installed by default. Lubuntu uses `synaptic` as the default graphical utility for installing and removing packages. There is [no `lubuntu-software-center` package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=lubuntu-software-center&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all).

Comment: Not a package, but I remember there being a software center for lubuntu (don't know the package name as I don't normally log in to Lubuntu's session or check for it's specifics :P)

Comment: I'd used Lubuntu actively for years and not heard of this, but that didn't mean it isn't so...so I looked into it. I'm glad I did. It turns out that there **is** a `lubuntu-software-center` package, but it **doesn't ship with any Lubuntu release** (including Lubuntu 11.10). [It appears that it was supposed to](http://news.softpedia.com/news/Introducing-Lubuntu-Software-Center-221531.shtml), but that it wasn't ready in time for Oneiric's release. It can be installed from the [`lubuntu-desktop` PPA](https://launchpad.net/~lubuntu-desktop/+archive/ppa). Thanks for mentioning this!

Answer (score 11):

## 12.04 and above

From Precise, the GTK version of UbuntuOne [is no longer supported](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntuone-control-panel/+bug/934270).

However is now an officially supported QT version of the Ubuntu-One client.

[image]

Whilst this QT-based app will adapt to your desktop-look, you have the option to make subtle changes via the QT-configuration utility `qt-config`

**how to install ubuntuone**

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntuone-control-panel-qt
```

**how to install qt-config**

```
sudo apt-get install qtconfig-qt4
```

Comment: Why I need qt-config?

Comment: @VitalyZdanevich - if you dont like the default look of this QT application - use qtconfig to change to one of the other QT themes.

Comment: I can confirm this works for Lubuntu 13.10 too.

Answer (score 5):

To get a little closer to Ubuntu integration, there is [a tip elsewhere](https://askubuntu.com/q/78442/35664) where you can add an option to right click on a folder to share it.

1. Start with a folder you want to share.
2. Right click on it.
3. Open With...
4. Custom Command Line
5. `u1sdtool --create-folder %f`

Now future folders should have that command in the context menu.

Comment: That's a very Nice tip!

Answer (score 1):

Use the command `sudo apt-get install ubuntuone-client-gnome`.

Comment: actually ubuntuone-client-gtk would be better so that you dont install gnome dependencies.