# How to integrate ubuntu one in pcmanfm (Lubuntu file manager)?

Tags: ubuntu-one, lubuntu

I have installed ubuntu-one on a Lubuntu machine and indeed the file syncing works for all the folder that are shared.

My problem is that while on my ubuntu machine I can right click a folder and mark it as shared, I could not find a way to do the same under pcmanfm.

The only workaround I was able to find is to use the daemon via command-line:

```
u1sdtool --create-folder .
```

which works but is kind of clumsy.... any way to integrate in the GUI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid this request and other U1 integration issues are on the [Lubuntu developers To-Do list](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lubuntu/Developers/TODO).

To summarise:

## likely projects:

- Ubuntu One - Pcmanfm integration - Need plugin infrastructure : TODO
- Ubuntu One - Audacious integration - Write a plugin : TODO

## discussed projects

- Ubuntu One - Sylpheed integration - Need plugin interface to contacts component : TODO
- Ubuntu One - Evaluate impact of additional programs to make it work : TODO
- Ubuntu One - Evaluate if it's possible to add support in Xpad
- Ubuntu One - Evaluate if it's possible / useful to add support in Osmo

Comment: Thank you for this (+1) I was not aware of the situation. Yet... I hope that somebody maybe has a workaround to propose [i.e. no plugin infrasctructure but a wonderful and ugly fix]...

Answer (score 1):

Here is an "ugly fix".  I'm not sure how wonderful it is though ;)

1. Right click a folder in PCManFM
2. Click "Open With..."
3. On the "Custom Command Line" tab, fill in "u1sdtool --create-folder %f"
4. Click OK

This should have added the folder to Ubuntu One like your command line did.  Also PCManFM should now show "u1sdtool --create-folder" on the right click menu for folders.