# Can you get Ubuntu Server on a mac?

Tags: server, mac, programming

I looked around for a bit and I haven't found the correct thread that fits my needs, I have an old mac Powerbook G4, I want to run Ubuntu Server on it, can I wipe out the entire harddrive and just run Ubuntu? (I don't need the Mac OS), or would I need to use a VM or dual boot. I tried a few things and it didn't work, I tried partitioning the hard drive and  burning the image, I tried using bootcamp but that did not work and tried both USB and Disk. I want to use the Ubuntu server just so I can get familiar with Linux servers and do my programming whenever I am on the road or not at my desktop. I don't know if I am doing something wrong, I maybe any help would be much appreciated.

Specs:

Mac OS X Version 10.5.8
Processor: 1.33 GHz PowerPC G4
Memory 2 GB DDR SDRAM
Processor: PowerBook G4 1.1
L2 Cache: 512kb

Answer (score 1):

You need a PowerPC iso. Have a look to https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PowerPCDownloads

Comment: can I access my Ubuntu One with Lubuntu?

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/36117/ubuntu-one-on-lubuntu

Comment: I played around with it until I got it to work.

Answer (score 0):

I played around with it until I got it to work,these are the steps I did:

- Downloaded the Lubuntu
- Copied the image on a CD
- inserted the CD, restarted the Mac.
- Hold down C until the boot menu comes up.
- Press Enter.
- And from there it is self explanatory,you chose your own partition settings and from there it is easy.